# Create a menu from a different channel on page with separate channel loop

Tags: channel-entries, templates, list, multiple-channels

I have a channel rendering a page. I need to make a menu for a different channel with in that page. the two do not seem to be able to work independently. Is there a way to do this

maybe something like this, only this doesn't work correctly.

Thanks for looking!

```
  {exp:channel:entries 
   channel="channel-1-content"
   limit="1"
   }

{some content}

{/exp:channel:entries}  

{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="channel-2-menu-items"
   limit="10"
   }
<ul>
<li><a href="{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
</ul>
{/exp:channel:entries} 

  {exp:channel:entries 
   channel="channel-1-content"
   limit="1"
   }

{some content}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding `dynamic=no` on your 2nd loop. By default channel entries look for a segment in the URL, adding dynamic tells it to ignore whatever's in the URL.